# Tablesorter filter widget, Tablesorter-filter and paging issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I am trying to add few dropdown filters on a table along with paging. I am using tableSorter plugins viz., tablesorter to sort, tablesorter-filter OR filter widget to filter and tablesorter pager for paging for this.

When I am using filter widget as in example at [filter widget example page](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html), it filters for only current page of paged data and paging is not updated then.

When I am using tablesorter-filter from this [jquery-tablesorter-filter location](https://github.com/jbritten/jquery-tablesorter-filter) as explained in the example on the same link, paging works fine but then I am not able to use dropdowns to select filtering option.

Does anyone know any workaround? (I need to use these tablesorter plugins at this moment so unfortunately trying other plugings is not option for me.. )

Comment: This issue should be resolved in tablesorter version 2.4... coming soon!

Answer (score 1):

Tablesorter version 2.4 is now live. Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager-filtered.html) of the pager plugin and filter widget working together. Just make sure that the pager plugin option removeRows is set to false:

```
$("table")
  .tablesorter()
  .tablesorterPager({ 
    // target the pager markup
    container: $(".pager"), 

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables. 
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; 
    // needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled. 
    removeRows: false, 
  });
```